# get value of an array's items within an object using the key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i need some solutions. 
Here is my situation; i want to get the value of an array's item within an object using the "KEY". For example, i have this object:

```
const obj = {
    id: 1,
    fields: [
        {id: 1, name: 'test'},
        {id: 2, name: 'test2'},
    ]
}
```

and i want to get name's value of the first element in fields. So the solution i know is that we can do: `obj['fields'][0]['name']` ... but what i'm looking for is just doing something like `obj[KEY]`.

So the question is: is that possible and what kind of ***KEY*** i can use to do it ?

Comment: it is not possible. you need a different approach, like an array with the keys and a fucntion for access. do you have a use case for it?

Comment: So it's not possible, yes we can do it using different approachs.
I have that case where i want to send a string like that `str = "fields[0].name"` an then according to my string get the value using my string and the entire object. I can do it simply if my object doesn't have arrays, if it has just objects by spliting my string `const keys = str.split('.')` and then using my keys to get the value.

Comment: @NinaScholz can you please explain how this question has already a solution because i checked the link you suggested and i did'nt found any duplication ?

Comment: you have an object/array and a string which should be used as key/s to the value. the access of an array is accessing an object. there is no difference.

Comment: No, it's not the same. My question is not about how to access array/object. I already know how to do it and i also know that there are lot of solutions. My question is about if i can use simply stuff like key to access an array's item value without doing that: `obj['fields'][0]['name']`.
Anyway tnk you so much, it was amazing to discuss with you about that subject

Comment: no, it is not possible. please see my first comment.

Comment: that was th answer of my question, not duplicate one. Tnk you man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. You are trying to access a nested value (the **property** of an **array item**, inside the **property** of an **object**).

Instead, you'll have to be explicit in how you access this field:
`obj.fields[0].name`.

What are you trying to achieve and why do you want to use a single key?

Comment: I have that case where i want to send a string like that `str = "fields[0].name"` and then according to my string get the value using my string and the entire object. I can do it simply if my object doesn't have arrays, if it has just objects by spliting my string `const keys = str.split('.')` and then using my keys to get the value